# Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have always get a warning when i click the button. I search it, they use bind to remove the warning but how can I add it to react redux in my code the bind function?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {toggleModal} from '../../actions/ModalActions';

interface Props {
    show?: boolean;
    onSelectedSample: (value: boolean) => void;
}

const SampleList = ({show, onSelectedSample}: Props) => {

  return (
     <div>
        <a  className='button link info' onClick={() => onSelectedSample(!show)}><i className='fa fa-user-plus fa-fw'></i></a>
        <a  className='button link info' onClick={() => onSelectedSample(!show)}><i className='fa fa-user-plus fa-fw'></i></a>
        <a  className='button link info' onClick={() => onSelectedSample(!show)}><i className='fa fa-user-plus fa-fw'></i></a>
      </div>
    );
});


const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
    return {
        show: state.modalReducer.show,
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, props) => {
    return {
        onSelectedSample: (toggle: boolean){
            dispatch(toggleModal(toggle));
        },
    };
};

const ListSampleContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SampleList);
export default ListSampleContainer;
```

It's hard if in redux code. I don't have any idea how to handle this in redux.

**Update**

Actions folder

```
import {ModalActions} from '../constants/ModalConstants';

export const toggleModal = (show?: boolean) => {
    return {
        type: ModalActions.TOGGLE_MODAL,
        show,
    };
};
```

Reducer folder

```
import {ModalActions} from '../constants/ModalConstants';

interface State {
    show: boolean;
}

const initState = {show: false};

export const modalReducer = (state: State = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ModalActions.TOGGLE_MODAL:
            if (action.show) {
                return {show: action.show};
            } else {
                return {show: !state.show};
            }

        case ModalActions.HIDE_MODAL:
            return {show: false};
    }
    return state;
};
```

If I have only one button. I don't have a warning but if more button added. That will happen

Comment: You used keyword `interface`... It is not really js?

Comment: .tsx(typescript)

Comment: what is the result of toggleModal in your reducer?

Comment: @MohamedIsmat I update my post.

Comment: @user3818576 do you need to add `onSelectedSample` to the `Props` interface and the parameters of `SampleList`? Note: I don't this is causing the error.

Comment: @MichaelPeyper  I add onSelectedSample in my props, but it only works if i have only one anchor in my div. If I add more anchor. That will happen, i get error

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  The interface should have no bearing on the number of times you use a value on it.

Comment: None of this code is calling `setState` and I doubt the redux `connect` wrapper is not handling state correctly.  Is there another component that gets displayed as a result of the `toggleModal` action (perhaps the modal)?

Comment: @MichaelPeyper I don't have another componet. My code works if only one button to be click. but if more button added. I get warning. I edit this part of my post const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
    return {
        show: state.modalReducer.show,
    };
};

Comment: Should `onSelectedSample: (toggle){` be `onSelectedSample: (toggle) => {` in `mapDispatchToProps` (not sure the former is even valid)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when you click one anchor, the others get clicked somehow because they are interleaving. Just to eliminate this possibility, try using different onClick handlers for the different anchors and see if you still have the error. Make every one of them log a different output to the console for example instead of dispatching your action. Then we'll know for sure.

```
<a  className='button link info' onClick={() => onSelectedSample1(!show)}><i className='fa fa-user-plus fa-fw'></i></a>
<a  className='button link info' onClick={() => onSelectedSample2(!show)}><i className='fa fa-user-plus fa-fw'></i></a>
<a  className='button link info' onClick={() => onSelectedSample3(!show)}><i className='fa fa-user-plus fa-fw'></i></a>
```